# Change the days into dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, forecasting

I am forecasting out-of-sample values from a dataframe called "yieldsp".It has a DateTime index. The tail of the dataset looks as follows:

```
yieldsp.tail()

            yieldsp
Date    
2020-06-24  0.54
2020-06-25  0.52
2020-06-26  0.50
2020-06-29  0.50
2020-06-30  0.50
```

I created an ARIMA(1,0,4) model and stored it as "model_fit" and I forecasted 7 future values of the yield spread. Since the last value of yieldsp is for 2020-06-30 in the dataset, the model forecasts values from 2020-07-01 to 2020-07-08.

```
X = yieldsp.values

# multi-step out-of-sample forecast

start_index = len(yieldsp)
end_index = start_index + 6

forecast = model_fit.predict(start=start_index, end=end_index)


history = [x for x in X]
day = 1

for yhat in forecast:
    print('Day %d: %f' % (day, yhat))
    history.append(forecast)
    day += 1
```

The result of the aforementioned code is:

```
Day 1: 0.504954
Day 2: 0.509603
Day 3: 0.512906
Day 4: 0.515455
Day 5: 0.517905
Day 6: 0.520350
Day 7: 0.522789
Day 8: 0.525224
```

My question is how do I change the code such that the result shows actual dates, instead of days? So, I would like it to display:

```
2020-07-01: 0.504954
2020-07-02: 0.509603
2020-07-03: 0.512906
2020-07-04: 0.515455
2020-07-05: 0.517905
2020-07-06: 0.520350
2020-07-07: 0.522789
2020-07-08: 0.525224
```

(Reference: I've taken the code snippets from [this website](https://machinelearningmastery.com/make-sample-forecasts-arima-python/) and modified it to apply in my dataset)

Comment: are you using statsmodels package for ARIMA model?

Comment: yes, I did: "from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA"

Comment: what is the index of the training data?

Comment: The index is still datetime.

Comment: then predicted values indexes should be actual dates.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use datetime object?

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

day = date(2020,7,1)

for yhat in forecast:
    print('Day {}: {}'.format(day, yhat))
    history.append(forecast)
    day += timedelta(days=1)
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks very much, @cafecotech. That was helpful! :)